# In D3, how can I support both Pan&Zoom and Mouseover on a force directed graph?

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 force directed graph.

I'd like to be able to Zoom and Pan the graph (working with the current code) but also mouse over the elements (not working because the `rect` used to capture the zoom/pan is covering the `circles` which should accep the `mouseover`. How can I support both functionalities?

```
const svg = select('svg');


const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");

var div = select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);


var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all")
  .call(zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", event.transform);
}

const simulation = forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("link", forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
  .force("charge", forceManyBody())
  .force("center", forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .on("tick", ticked);


const focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .style("display", "none");

const link = g.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#999")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value));

const node = g.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", (d) => d.group === 1 ? '#ff0000' : '#0000ff')
  .call(drag(simulation))

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  }
```

Comment: set the zoom on the svg, do a search on SO. this is asked a lot (zoom a force graph) and there are lots of blocks examples

Answer (score 0):

As @rioV8 mentioned all you have to do is apply the zoom to SVG. Pretty straightforward.

Here's the full code in case anyone is interested:

css

```
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tooltip {  
  position: absolute;           
  text-align: center;           
  padding: 2px; 
  font: 15px sans-serif;        
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;      
  border-radius: 8px;           
  pointer-events: none;         
}
```

javascript

```
const {
  nodes,
  links
} = await this.getData();

console.log(nodes)
console.log(links.map(({
  source,
  target
}) => source + '->' + target).join('\n'))

const svg = select('svg');


const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");

// Define the div for the tooltip
var tooltip = select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)


const zoomHandler = zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 10])
  .on("zoom", () => g.attr("transform", event.transform));

zoomHandler(svg);

const simulation = forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("link", forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
  .force("charge", forceManyBody())
  .force("center", forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .on("tick", ticked);

const link = g.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#999")
  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", d => d.value);

const node = g.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", (d) => d.group === 1 ? '#ff0000' : '#0000ff')
  .on("mouseover", function (d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", .9);

      tooltip.html(d.id)
      .style("left", (event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function (d) {
    tooltip.transition()
      .duration(100)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
  .call(drag(simulation))

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

  node
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}
```